# Rename tag from papertrail to paper_trail

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [papertrail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/papertrail) tag is concerned with ruby's [paper_trail](https://rubygems.org/gems/paper_trail) gem, which I help maintain.

Adding the underscore to the tag could help distinguish between [paper_trail](https://rubygems.org/gems/paper_trail) the gem, and [Papertrail Inc.](https://papertrailapp.com/) the company. Confusing the two is a somewhat common mistake.

Comment: Is papertrail only being used for paper_trail? There is no other usage you have seen? Perhaps a synonym would be better in that case. Have you seen questions where they made the mistake with the company?

Comment: Underscores are automatically converted to hyphens in tag names, so you'd end up with [tag:paper-trail] which isn't really any less ambiguous. Would something like [tag:paper-trail-gem] work?

Comment: Yes, [paper-trail-gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paper-trail-gem) sounds good to me.  There are other major gems that use this suffix, like [i18n-gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i18n-gem) so we wouldn't be the first.

Answer (score 4):

I've gone ahead and split this up into the two tags:

1. [papertrail-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/papertrail-app) was created for the log management app (sorry for the lack of a better tag name), and questions about it were retagged.

   I assumed everything tagged with Ruby was about paper_trail and only looked at the others to retag to papertrail-app. Please retag any that are not actually relevant.
2. Renamed the tag for all remaining questions to [paper-trail-gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paper-trail-gem).